# Getting object name in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class Animal

    def initialize(noise)
        @noise = noise
    end

    def say
        puts "#{self.class} does #{@noise}"
    end

end

dog = Animal.new("Woof Woof")
cat = Animal.new("Meow Meow")

dog.say
cat.say
```

How can I print `dog does woof woof` instead of `Animal does Woof Woof`?

Comment: Issue not clear. If you had `dog = cat = Animal.new("Woof Woof")`, then how would you expect the output to be? `dog does ...`, `cat does ...`, `dog cat does ...`, `cat dog does ...`, `dogcat does ...`, or, something else?

Comment: Only classes and modules store the [`name`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-name) of the (first) constant they were assigned to. Other objects are not aware of the variable(s) or constant(s) they were (possibly) assigned to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear, Animal is the name of the class you have created. That is why when you

```
puts " #{self.class} etc... "
```

the text Animal appears.

Now in your example, cat and dog are the names of variables. These are nothing more than references to the objects you create in the lines:

```
dog = Animal.new("Woof Woof")
cat = Animal.new("Meow Meow")
```

The variable may be called dog or cat, but the class remains Animal. To my knowledge, there is no good way to get name of a variable, short of some really convoluted introspection tools.

On the other hand: If you simply want your animals to have names, consider adding a name attribute.

```
class Animal
  def initialize(name, noise)
    @name = name
    @noise = noise
  end

  def say
    puts "#{@name} does #{@noise}"
  end
end

dog = Animal.new("Dog", "Woof Woof")
cat = Animal.new("Cat", "Meow Meow")

dog.say
cat.say
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a code misunderstanding, no big deal. `Animal` IS the object, that's why it will always print `Animal does Woof Woof`. You know that `Animal` is the object because you've declared it: `class Animal`, a class is an object.

`dog` is an instance of that `Animal` class. If you want to print the instance name, then you need to actually create an attribute, just like you've done with `@noise`. So, one example might be:

```
def initialize(noise, name) 
  @noise = noise
  @name = name
end

dog = Animal.new("Woof Woof", "dog")
```

Note you'll probably want to not pass `params` individually but in a `params` hash, so it becomes clearer to read.