# How to print out value and name of each arg from a splat argument list

Tags: ruby

I have

```
a = 'a string'
b = 3
```

I use this common pattern:

```
puts "a: #{a}, b: #{a}"
```

I would like to do this with a method e.g.,

```
def puts_auto(*args)
  str = args.map { |arg| "#{arg.object_name #{a}" }.join('')
  puts str
end
```

where `object_name` finds the name of the object that was used to create the arg. Is there such method like `object_name`? Is there a way to print the value and the name of each argument from a splat argument list?

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question really? I don’t see how variable assignments are related to splat parameters.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49121443/1779477 answer your question?

Comment: The comment I just posted disappeared. Why? Who? It merely said that I thought @idmean's question should be answered in the affirmative.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2603617/754004

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby - print the variable name and then its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603617/ruby-print-the-variable-name-and-then-its-value)

Comment: Obromios, only moderators can remove comments.

Comment: What is `joins`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754004/mark)'s suggestion in regard to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603617/ruby-print-the-variable-name-and-then-its-value), the following works

```
  def puts_auto (*args, &b)
    str = args.map { |arg| "#{arg} = #{eval(arg.to_s, b.binding)}" }.join(', ')
    puts str
  end
```

so

```
puts_auto(:a, :b){} # outputs `a = a string, b = 3`
```